# How can I detect airtag directly in my app

Tags: ios

Is there a way to find the distance to the airtag by making my own app other than the "Find My" app?

Additionally, airtag is not recognized in the test app provided by Apple.
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/nearbyinteraction/implementing_interactions_between_users_in_close_proximity)

Is the nearby interaction framework available only on iPhone 11 or later, Apple Watch, and third-party accessories, not on devices with all u1 chips?

Comment: nearby interaction is for apps running on iOS devices.  It is not for interacting with AirTags.  There are no public apis for AirTags